# Vaadin-combo-box converting array to [object Object] when using in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vaadin, ag-grid, vaadin-core-elements

I am using Vaadin-combo-box in ag-grid but don't know why array converting to [object Object].

Below is code for ag-grid

```
columnDefs = [{
   headerName: "Students",
   field: "studentId",
   cellRenderer: this.renderStudentDropdown
}]


renderStudentDropdown(){
const records = [{"id": "123", "title" : "Student 1"},{"id": "456", "title" : "Student 2"}]
let html = `<vaadin-combox-box .items=${templates} .value='${value}' item-label-path="title" item-value-path="id"></vaadin-combox-box>`;
return html
}
```

after rendering in browser, its not showing data in drop down and print data like [object Object]

[image]

Comment: That seems to be the syntax used for lit-html templates, those need to be run through the `html` template tag.

Comment: `cellRenderer` expects final html string which should be injected in DOM. You need to `compile` your vaadin components so that you get final html string - I am not quite sure how you can do that. Better approach here would be to use `cellRendererFramework`

Comment: @Paritosh - this html string is converting and injected in DOM but only data is not converting. I used `cellRendererFramework` but its giving me error.

@ErikLumme - you are right. I am using lit-html but if I use return html`<div>hi</div>`, then its not render the div and break the ag-grid